# How to install packages that is already downloaded?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I am new to linux environment.I am using windows. Recenty I downloaded the google chrome and tried to install it but failed.Then I saw a tutorial which had this command

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

It will download the package again but I have already downloaded it using mozilla. Is there any terminal window command that I can use in place of this above command to access an install package from a specified path and install it?

The Tutorial link is: http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-google-chrome-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you've downloaded is .deb file, then what you do, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded, most likely the Downloads folder, and run the commands below.

```
sudo dpkg -i <filename.deb>
```

Comment: Do I have to navigate to that specific folder? Then run this command?

Comment: yes, read the answer carefully. or type `sudo dpkg -i ` then drag the file to terminal.

Comment: And one more last thing I have sudo dpkg -i and then is it done or I nedd to do more to install it? I can't find chrome any where after doing this?

Comment: OR just double click the deb file. It will open in Software Center and then click Install

Comment: @Neer No, after the dpkg process is complete, chrome should be installed and working. Run it as you usually run your applications (from the dash, launcher...)